# retrieving Data does not appear in fragment in ListView

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve saved contacts from Firebase real time database. Contacts are saved in Firebase realtime database.but does not retrieve.when user accept the chat request then his name has been saved in contacts node in database.I want to retrieve this saved contact in contact fragment but data is not appear in fragment. help me please. here is the code:

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ContactsFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">





    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

> java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {
    private View ContactsView;
    private RecyclerView myContactsList;
    private DatabaseReference ContactsRef,UsersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID;


    public ContactsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       ContactsView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
       myContactsList=(RecyclerView) ContactsView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
       myContactsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
       ContactsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);
       UsersRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

       return ContactsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                .setQuery(ContactsRef,Contacts.class)
                .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts,ContactsViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ContactsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContactsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contacts model) {
                String userIDs=getRef(position).getKey();
                UsersRef.child(userIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Image")){
                            String userProfileImage=dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();
                            String profileName=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String profileStatus=dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            holder.userName.setText(profileName);
                            holder.userStatus.setText(profileStatus);
                            Picasso.get().load(userProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);

                        }
                        else {
                            String profileName=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String profileStatus=dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            holder.userName.setText(profileName);
                            holder.userStatus.setText(profileStatus);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                View view=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout,viewGroup,false);
                ContactsViewHolder viewHolder=new ContactsViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
    }
    public static class ContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName,userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;
        public ContactsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            profileImage=(CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `startListening` to  begin populating data:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

From the docs:

> The FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter listens for scrolling events and loads additional pages from the database only when needed.
>
> To begin populating data, call the startListening() method. You may want to call this in your onStart() method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling startListening() or your query will fail.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md